# Как удалить кнопку с клавиатуры телеграм бот (Python)

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Пишу игру виселица на питон.Как сделать так,чтобы после нажатия кнопки на клавиатуре,эта кнопка автоматически удалялась?

```
 import random



       import telebot
        from telebot import types

        bot = telebot.TeleBot("")
        @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
        def send_welcome(message):
            global s
            s=0
            global a
            global b
            global n
            global lis

            spisok=['автострада','спасибо']
            a=random.choice(spisok)
            b=(list(a))
            n=list(("*"*len(a)))
            markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1=types.KeyboardButton("а")
            item2=types.KeyboardButton("б")
            item3=types.KeyboardButton("в")
            item4=types.KeyboardButton("г")
            item5=types.KeyboardButton("д")
            item6=types.KeyboardButton("е")
            item7=types.KeyboardButton("ё")
            item8=types.KeyboardButton("ж")
            item9=types.KeyboardButton("з")
            item10=types.KeyboardButton("и") 
            item11=types.KeyboardButton("й")
            item12=types.KeyboardButton("к")
            item13=types.KeyboardButton("л")
            item14=types.KeyboardButton("м")
            item15=types.KeyboardButton("н")
            item16=types.KeyboardButton("о")
            item17=types.KeyboardButton("п")
            item18=types.KeyboardButton("р")
            item19=types.KeyboardButton("с")
            item20=types.KeyboardButton("т")
            item21=types.KeyboardButton("у")
            item22=types.KeyboardButton("ф")
            item23=types.KeyboardButton("х")
            item24=types.KeyboardButton("ц")
            item25=types.KeyboardButton("ч")
            item26=types.KeyboardButton("ш")
            item27=types.KeyboardButton("щ")
            item28=types.KeyboardButton("ъ")
            item29=types.KeyboardButton("ы")
            item30=types.KeyboardButton("ь")
            item31=types.KeyboardButton("э")
            item32=types.KeyboardButton("ю")
            item33=types.KeyboardButton("я")


            markup.add(item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10,item11,item12,item13,item14,item15,item16,item17,item18,item19,item20,item21,item22,item23,item24,item25,item26,item27,item28,item29,item30,item31,item32,item33)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет,сейчас ты сыграешь в игру виселица")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ''.join(n))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите одну букву")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Количество твоих жизней: ❤❤❤❤❤",reply_markup=markup )

        @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
        def text(message):

            global lis
            global s
            if message.text in b:
                for idx, symbol in enumerate(b):
                    if symbol == message.text:
                        n[idx] = symbol 

                        if n==b:
                            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Поздравляю")
                            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы выиграли")
                            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Загаданное слово:")
                            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ''.join(n))
                            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Чтобы начать заново, нажмите /start")
                            return
            else:

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Данной буквы нет")
                s+=1
                if s==1:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Осталось жизней:  ❤❤❤❤")


                if s==2:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Осталось жизней:  ❤❤❤")

                if s==3:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Осталось жизней:  ❤❤")

                if s==4:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Осталось жизней:  ❤")

                if s==5:

                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы превысили количество попыток, игра закончена.")
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Чтобы начать заново, нажмите /start")
                    return
            del message.text
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ''.join(n))

        bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант – определить общую клавиатуру в список. Затем, при старте игры сделать копию списка и после нажатия на кнопку пользователем создать новую клавиатуру из нового списка, предварительно удалив из него ту кнопку, которая была нажата. И так раз за разом до конца игры. Абсолютно новую клавиатуру создать из исходного списка только при старте игры.